# C++ Hiding Symbols increases relocation time

Tags: c++, optimization, visibility, symbols, elf

I am trying to optimize the loading time of a library with more than 200 dependencies. I tried hiding symbols using visibility attributes which led me to reduce the number of exported symbols by 30%.

Looking at the elf histogram the number of buckets remain the same after the optimization but the successful and unsuccessful lookup decreased a lot. The bloom filter size decreased from 8kb to 4kb but the number of bits set increased from 19% to 24%.

Despite that the loading time increased and I think it is due to the number of bits set in the bloom filter higher then before.

Looking at the dependencies I can see that there are around 400.000 symbols that at relocation time are looked into my library without success.  The bloom filter used to filters most of them but the number of false positives increased from 3.6% to 5,76% due to the higher  number of bit sets(I found this formula on internet: false positive=bitsets%^2)

Doing some maths before optimization I had to search into my library 14.440 false positive and after the optimization this number rised to 23.040. Even if the unsuccessful lookup decreased from 1.7 to 1.1 the number of comparisons is still higher then before.

I tested it also with calgrind that confirmed that the optimization decreased the performance of the library. The library itself is around 2% faster than before but the relocation time is around 1% higher(in ld strcmp calls rised from 3575000 to 3617000).

I tried also to reduce further the number of exported symbols using the export map that helped me to reduce the number of exported symbols by 50%. But it was even worst. The number of buckets are the half but the unsuccessful lookup raised to 1.4 the bloom filter size to 2kb with a bit sets of 29% with 8.4% of false positive.

How it is possible that hiding symbols increase the number of comparisons done at relocation time? If the bloom filter affects so much the results, why the linker prefer to reduce its size instead of decreasing the % of false positives? Is there any linker option that can help me in this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The bloom filter size decreased from 8kb to 4kb but the number of bits set increased from 19% to 24%....what does this mean??did the buckets in bloom filter come down?

Comment: The Bloom filter is a bitset where the linker set 2 bits for every symbol exported by the library using hash functions. It is used at relocation(loading) time to know if a symbol is defined in a library or not (the filter is probabilistic:false positive matches are possible, but false negatives are not). The bigger is the filter, bigger will be the memory used at relocation time but smaller will be the number of false positive. If you have constraint of loading time and not of memory is much better to have a bigger bloom filter and a smaller false positive rate in the relocation process.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into something similar for a media player app sometime ago.

Use of `direct binding` does help to reduce the symbol resolution time.

Not sure about the impact of hiding symbols on bloom filter.

> Is there any linker option that can help me in this?

As far as I know, there is no way to tune the bloom filter used in symbol lookup.

There are some good articles out there, but none emphasise on tuning bloom filter.

[bloom filter elf](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/gnu_hash_elf_sections)

[cost of elf symbol](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/the_cost_of_elf_symbol)